Z-A-Z (a grid with digits)
Fill in the question marks with the correct values (some can be blank). What's your mood like today anyway?

1  1     13  1 1    11  1
  1             11
      2 11  11    1
  1           1    1  1
    1    1     1   1 1
 1 1   111     1    ?????
        1   12      ?????
 1  1 1  1  1   1   ?????
          1  1      ?????
                  1 ?????
   11   1 11   1        1
        1 1 1    1     1
  1 1 11   1
   11        1   11  1  1
          1         1
1 1      21 1 1     1
      1   1       1
 11   1 1  1   1
         1  1   11     3
          1    1   1    1
   1 1         1   1    1
   2   1      1   1    1
  1        2  1   1     1
    1   11            12
         1    1 1   1


Well, I'm feeling pretty...

 RELAXED.

Because this image depicts...

 ...the chart of Pokémon natures and their effects on a Pokémon's base stats.


Source: pokemondb.net

To read it as such...

 ...focus on each black-edged box and imagine that the letters from A-Y are written inside it as a 5x5 grid.



 Now the numbers in each of these black-rimmed boxes represents the quantities of each of these letters that appear in the names of the 25 Pokémon natures. These are (row by row):

 HARDY, LONELY, ADAMANT, NAUGHTY, BRAVE,
 BOLD, DOCILE, IMPISH, LAX, RELAXED,
 MODEST, MILD, BASHFUL, RASH, QUIET,
 CALM, GENTLE, CAREFUL, QUIRKY, SASSY,
 TIMID, HASTY, JOLLY, NAIVE, SERIOUS.

 As an example, look at the middle one on the top row - we have 3 A's, 1 D, 1 M, 1 N and 1 T, which together anagram to spell ADAMANT. You can do likewise for all the others.



The missing one represented by question marks...

 ...should represent the absent 'RELAXED'. With 1 A, 1 D, 2 E's, 1 L, 1 R and 1 X, it should appear like so:




As for the title, I read it as rot13(mrq-yrff N gb M) though that may not exactly match the OP's intent :)

Yep, it's also somewhat of a reference to the upcoming rot13(Cbxrzba Yrtraqf: M-N)
